# URL link in Rich Text inside of Webview

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, richtextbox, richtext

I have been trying to figure this one out for a while but I just can't seem to find an answer. I have an app that I am working on that contains rich text within a WebView, I would like to be able to add a hyperlink within that but I just don't know how.

This is my code:

```
+(NSArray*)getSampleData
```

{

```
NSString* content0 = @"<b><u>For Printer Models:</b></u> IJ2040, 3000, 3160. </p><p>Cable Part Number: CD-023A. </p><p>Connector: RJ12. </p><p>Interface Type: <ul><li><p>12 Volt MultiPRO II: 420</li></p><li><p>12/24 Volt MultiPRO III: 520.</ul></p><p>Manufacturer Website: www.addmaster.com";
```

}

```
BusinessService* service0 = [[BusinessService alloc] initWithCaption:@"Addmaster" andImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"interface.jpg"] andWebContentTitle:@"Connectors for Addmaster" andWebContent:content0 andWebContentImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"interface.jpg"]];
```

Now I would like to be able to link directly from the webview to www.addmaster.com so that anyone reading that, can just click on the link to open up safari. Please let me know if it is possible. Thank you very much for your help.